# Unable to find bundled Java version error on Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

```
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
• Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.
```

I've tried to solve this problem with "cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre", but there is no jre file in Contents folder.

I was trying to install flutter.
And to solve this problem I've downloaded openjdk version "16.0.1" and also re-installed android studio again

Comment: I am facing the same error, if you got the solution please share

Comment: The solution was:
Access to the path which is installed the Android Studio (You could find the path using "flutter doctor -v")
then, move to Contents directory and create 'jre' folder
next, move to jbr directory to copy Contents folder and paste it in jre folder we've created just before
finally, execute "flutter doctor -v" command again!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Add this path]

After installing java add this path...